# manipulate a string for opening word document

Tags: c#, ms-word

Based on [Opening Word document within C# that has spaces in the path](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9935404). I'd like to ask how to do the same but when the path is acquired from list box. I know that if I use `@"path"` it will work, but how do I do the same to `listBox.SelectedItem.ToString()` when opening

```
var _p = new Process();
_p.StartInfo.FileName = "Word.exe"
_p.StartInfo.Arguments = lbFiles.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

Let's say I want to open "C:\new word document.docx". **Word** gives an error can't find path "C:\new.doc" any ideas how to do it.

Comment: `"Word.exe"` is just for **presentation** the valuer is taken from registry baseed on this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9540051/is-an-application-associated-with-a-given-extension/9540278#9540278)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try surrounding the file name in quotes as well:

```
_p.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("\"{0}\"", lbFiles.SelectedItem);
```

Also, `Word.exe` doesn't work on my system. You may need to change that to:

```
_p.StartInfo.FileName = "WinWord.exe"
```

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.dll

Additional information: Cannot start process because a file name has not been provided.

Comment: "\"C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\New Microsoft Word Document.docx\""

Comment: this is the result I get ( with your solution )

Comment: I take the _p.StartInfo.FileName - from registry based on this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9540051/is-an-application-associated-with-a-given-extension/9540278#9540278)

Comment: so `WinWord.exe` is not relevant but the path string should be some way to manipulate it

Comment: positive 100% it gets to the list from open file dialog. also it breaks the name of the file and tries to search for each part.like new.doc microsoft.doc etc ... each space is a different search

Comment: Also it works for `New Text Document.txt` and it's opened automatically in the notepad ( as defined by the registry ) as I said it's strange and it occurs only with WORD.

Comment: I'll humor you more then you think, tried `"WinWord.exe"` - worked !! after changed back to the registry - **Worked also :)**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62906/discussion-between-light-user-and-grant-winney).